# expiringdict, print right before expiration

Tags: python

I have data representing a journey (multiple nodes) that can end in multiple points. I don't know where it's going to end. I know the meantime it can take. When the journey ends, I need to print its information. Because of the lack of control, I was willing to use an expiration dictionary.

```
self._assets_history = ExpiringDict(max_len=100, max_age_seconds=10*60)  # 10 minutes of cache
```

The problem is that I can't find a clean way to print the content of a given item in the dictionary, right before it is deleted.

Comment: Is this the class from https://github.com/mailgun/expiringdict ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, yes, it is.

Comment: You can overwrite `__delitem__` in a derived class to be informed about any deletion or can edit the source to replace any expiration-caused delete by a method call. This new method can then do something (like print) and finally handle the deletion.